# I got a rejection email for postdoc position along with an invitation to apply as a visiting assistant professor. Is this a gentle letdown?

Tags: postdocs, job-search, email

I applied for a postdoctoral position, and I got an email from hiring committee :

"Thank you for applying  ~ positions.  All positions have been filled.
But we have been authorized to fill a Visiting Assistant Professor (VAP) position starting ~. If you are interested in being considered for this new position, please let me know ASAP."

Is this a gentle letdown? Or is it means that there's a high chance for me to get an offer for VAP?

Comment: It means precisely what it says. It’s a mistake to read anything into it that isn’t stated explicitly. They are encouraging you to apply to the VAP position, and will consider you if you apply.

Answer (score 57, accepted):

It means that there is *some* chance for you to get the visiting position. As opposed to "go away, no chance".

I'd wager that it's not clear what your chances are, but that there are *some* chances... Better a visiting position than no job, I think.

Comment: Isn't VAP just another word for postdoc?

Comment: @cgb5436 VAP (visiting assistant Professor) may be not as long as a postdoc 1 or 2 years vs 3 years. Otherwise it is the same.

Comment: @ cgb5436  In my experience, a VAP has a higher teaching load than a postdoc, most of the time.  There are many exceptions.

Comment: @cgb5436, a Vis. Asst. Prof position may only be for a single year, and will probably tend to have a higher teaching load than a "postdoc". A postdoc is for two or three years, and supposedly designed to help the person's research program, with a reduced teaching load.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. And Yes the postdoc position was for 3 years with a reduced teaching load.

Comment: There are too many assumptions in these comments. Read the announcement. A VAP could be (US) up to about six years, at which time the rules may require a tenure decision or an end.

Comment: @Buffy, currently, in math, in the U.S., it seems that "visiting" asst prof is _not_ tenure-track, and will _not_ last several years. Not that I can't imagine otherwise, but I've not seen any examples recently.

Comment: @paulgarrett, no, it isn't TT, but there is (or was) a principle in some places and the policy of one org (IIRC) that says that if you get hired in year 7 you have tenure. My information is old, of course.

Comment: @paulgarrett, see this for current thinking: https://www.aaup.org/issues/tenure

Comment: @Buffy, ah, yes, there is often some bait-and-switch, especially at some fancy places, where junior faculty are strung along as supposedly tenure-track, but never really had a chance... Similarly, the number of "visiting" (meaning no hope of tenure, and possibly no job the next year...) has increased alarmingly. Years ago, it seemed that most "visiting" faculty positions were for people who had a long-term job elsewhere, and were taking a sabbatical, ... That's not currently typical (in math, in the U.S., ...)

Comment: @Jib To be clear, if this is a position you would be interested in you should definitely apply.

Comment: @chessofnerd I just applied. Thank you for your advice!